# Biblatex: Use the cite tracker to refer to the number of the citation's first occurrence

Tags: biblatex

I want to achieve the following behavior using a custom footnote citation style for the second and subsequent occurrence of a citation within a document:

**LaTeX:**

```
Sample Text\footcite{foo}. Some more dummy text.\footcite{bar} Lorem ipsum\footcite{foo}.
```

**Output:**

*Sample Text^1. Some more dummy text.^2 Lorem ipsum^3.*

With the following footnote content:

*^1 Standard output of the \cite command for entry **foo** as defined in the style.*

*^2 Standard output of the \cite command for entry **bar** as defined in the style.*

*^2 See fn. 1.*

And if possible it would be great if this behavior would also apply to a `\footcites` command which includes a yet cited bib entry.

I hope my question became clear enough and that my research on this topic, which yielded zero hits, was comprehensive.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your general question is quite clear, but you are quite short on details. Do you want to modify an existing style? Would you be OK switching to a new style? What are the further requirements for your style? What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex` already has some styles that implement a behaviour like this: [`verbose-note`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/72-style-verbose-note-biber.pdf) and [`verbose-inote`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/73-style-verbose-inote-biber.pdf).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-note]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
  ipsum\autocite{worman}
  dolor\autocite{cicero}       
  sit\autocite{sigfridsson}       
  amet\autocite{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: footnotes of MWE]

---

The infrastructure needed is a macro that saves the footnote number

```
\newbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
  \csxdef{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}%
  \label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}}
```

This macro needs to be executed at the very first citation of a work (and only then).

And then a macro that utilises this, the relevant parts of `footcite:note` are

```
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
          \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}
```

(All copied from `verbose-note.cbx`.)

Comment: +1. :-) On a completely different subject: May I ask you to take a look at [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361416/5001) and decide if it's possible to provide a biblatex-based solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Mico Seems to be more or less standard `biblatex` behaviour. I have attempted an answer, but I'm not sure if I overlooked something.

Comment: Thanks so much! Let's see if the OP weighs in with further information. :-)